# UNO Stacking a Draw 4 Card instead of picking up 4 cards?

Tags: house-rules, uno

Need clarification on the Draw 4 rule.
- Player 1 lays down a Draw 4 Card and says the color is Red.
- Player 2 does not have a Red card but has a Draw 4 Card.
Can Player 2 lay down his Draw 4 Card and have Player 3 draw 8 cards?

Comment: Interestingly, the "original" version of uno in Brazil - [Can-Can](https://cdn.serounaosei.com/wp-content/uploads/20170803082815/jogo-can-can-da-grow-anos-80-completo-407601-MLB20380036605_082015-O-300x225.jpg) - had special house-rules built-in in the game manual for this situation. Stacking +2 cards was baseline, where stacking +4 or +1 cards was optional. Uno took away the +1 cards, and removed the stacking mechanics.

Answer (score 14):

Not under the standard rules - there is *no* ability to respond to a Wild +4 (or a +2 for that matter). If the previous player to you played one of those cards, you take the cards and the turn pass.

"Stacking" + cards is a common house rule, but we obviously can't tell you what your house rules are.

Comment: This was recently clarified by the designers of Uno on their twitter thread.

Comment: It should be noted that there is no ability to other cards such as a skip or reverse as well.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not valid to do so since according to the Mattel's UNO rules the next player forfeit their turn and MUST draw 4 cards from the pile.

From mattel.com: https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf

> Wild Draw 4 Card - This card allows you to call the next color played and requires the next player to pick 4 cards from the DRAW pile and FORFEIT his/her turn.

*Note: Stacking or Progressive UNO, i.e. playing a Draw 4 card (on top of another Draw 4 card) instead of picking up 4 cards, is a house rule used by some.*

Answer (score 2):

According to official rules, if a player plays a `Wild Draw 4` card on you, you can only:

1. Draw 4 cards.
2. You may challenge that player, if you suspect that a Wild Draw 4 card has been played on you illegally (i.e. the player has a matching card). The challenged player
   must show you their hand. If guilty, the challenged player must draw
   the 4 cards instead of you. However, if the challenged player is innocent, you must draw
   the 4 cards PLUS an additional 2 cards (6 total).

Reference:
https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/UNO%20Basic%20IS.pdf

Comment: This does not appear to add anything new to the question that was not addressed in a previous answer.

Comment: I am answering EXACTLY what you can do when someone throws a "Draw 4" card.

Comment: But you don't answer the question about the common house rule of stacking draw cards. The only thing that was really new to the question is the challenge rule which wasn't being asked about.

Comment: I agree with Joe W that the question was about the stacking house rule and your answer is about something else that wasn't asked about.

Comment: I am sure there will be people who appreciate this clarification that complements the rest of the answers. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this question is a reference to a tweet that was viral over last few days.   So direct from source.....

If someone puts down a +4 card, you must draw 4 and your turn is skipped. You can’t put down a +2 to make the next person Draw 6. We know you’ve tried it. [#UNO](https://twitter.com/hashtag/UNO?src=hash&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) [pic.twitter.com/wOegca4r0h](https://t.co/wOegca4r0h)— UNO (@realUNOgame) [May 4, 2019](https://twitter.com/realUNOgame/status/1124720366130204672?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)