# Playing a draw 4 after another player has played a draw 4

Tags: uno

- The first player lays down a draw 4 card.
- The second player draws 4 cards.
- The third player lays down a draw 4 card as well.

Does that mean the second player puts back their 4 cards. While the fourth player has to draw 8 cards?

Comment: Having players put cards back as part of the game (without this explicitly being stated in the text or rule for the card itself) would make for rather confusing gameplay that possibly enables cheating (unless you allow them to put *any* cards in their hand back instead of what they just drew) and gives that player information that other players don't have about which cards are still in the deck. It's not impossible for such a rule to exist in a popular game, but it seems unlikely.

Answer (score 20):

No.

The first player's action caused the second player to draw four cards and skip their normal turn; there is nothing in the rules which can cause that to be "undone". The third player's turn then proceeds as normal.

It may be worth noting here [that "stacking" Draw 2 or Draw 4 cards is not part of the official rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47143/uno-stacking-a-draw-4-card-instead-of-picking-up-4-cards) even if it is a common house rule.

Comment: Also worth noting that you can play a wild whenever you want, but can only play a Wild Draw 4 if you do not have a card of the current color

Comment: @Kevin That's true, but the point of this answer isn't to explain all the rules of Uno. The original poster stated what happened, and I'm going to assume they were legal plays unless there's a reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: The original poster also thought the "follow-on" or "stacking" rule was an official rule, and in those rules, you can play a Wild Draw 4 when it wouldn't otherwise be legal if the player before you did so. (Typically.  Table variation is likely.) So it could be worth clarifying in this case, because of assumptions drawn in the question.

Comment: Exactly. There's a difference here between official rule and common house rules. Stacking draw cards is not possible under official rules. What will happen under house rules is of-course up to the house. Likely outcomes are that either each time the target player draws 4 or the last player draws the total (12).

Comment: @Kevin That is not true, you can play a wild draw 4 if you have a card of the current color. However you can be challenged for that action and if it is determined that you indeed do have a card of that color you have to draw 4 instead of the player in question. If you do not they draw 6 instead. This is important to note because in every digital version I have played you can play the wild draw 4 whenever you want and the next player gets the option to challenge it if they think you have a card of the color that was in play before the wild draw 4.